# How to get an arraylist reference from an CustomAdapter in android?

Tags: java, android

I made an GridView to organize TextView and Edit views, like a table , programatically, using an CustomAdapter. In getView() override method i create the views, add it to a arrayList and let the abstraction do its job. The problem arises when i try to acess the views outside the adapter class, in this case, in OnCreate of the activity. I was trying to get the array through getItems() method which returns the arrayList of views. But it returns am empty array (i check with a log that prints 0). And i'm wondering why is that happening? maybe the getView() methods runs only after i try to get the array in onCreate, somehow the onCreate finishes before the adapter is fully ready?
and if that's the case, where/when should i get the views?
Here's my activity and adapter class:

```
 public class MatrizMultiplicationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MatrizGridAdapter gridAdapter;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_matriz_mult);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setNumColumns(5);
        gridAdapter = new MatrizGridAdapter(this,5,5);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        ArrayList<EditText> matrix = gridAdapter.getItems();
        Log.d("mSize", String.valueOf(matrix.size()));
    }
    public class MatrizGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context ctx;
        int rows;
        int coluns;
        int size;
        ArrayList<EditText> views;

        public MatrizGridAdapter(Context ctx, int rows, int coluns)
        {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.rows=  rows;
            this.coluns = coluns;
            this.size = rows*coluns;
            this.views = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        }

       // .. some methods

        public ArrayList<EditText> getItems()
        {
            return views;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public EditText getItem(int position) {
            if((views.size()<position))
            {
                return views.get(position);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                CardView cardview = new CardView(ctx);
               //code for setting CardView attributes
               //...
               //..
               //layout logic, doesn't really matter
                if(position==0)
                {
                    TextView textView = new TextView(ctx);
                   //code for setting textView attributes
                    cardview.addView(textView);
                    cardview.setBackgroundColor(R.color.cinzarrom);

                }
                //layout logic, doesn't really matter
                //it is the first row, so put the numbers of coluns above
                else if(position<coluns)
                {
                   //code for setting textView attributes
                   //...
                   //..
                    cardview.addView(textView);
                    cardview.setBackgroundColor(R.color.cinzarrom);
                    setMarginLeft(textView, MyMath.convertDpToPixels(20,ctx));
                }
                //it is the first colun in any row, so put the number of rows on the left
                else if(position%coluns==0)
                {
                   //code for setting textView attributes
                    cardview.addView(textView);
                    cardview.setBackgroundColor(R.color.cinzarrom);
                    setMarginLeft(textView, MyMath.convertDpToPixels(20,ctx));
                }
                //ARE THE VIEWS BEING ADDED BEFORE THE CALL TO ARRAY.SIZE?()
                 else {
                    EditText editText = new EditText(ctx);
                    //add it to the array who stores the text views
                    views.add(editText);
                    //code for setting textView attributes
                    cardview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    cardview.addView(editText);
                }
                return cardview;
            }

            return convertView;
        }
}
```

Comment: An adapter uses a pool of views, some are on the screen at the time, some are off the screen. This is under the adapters control. Why are you wanting to have this getItems method?

Comment: It is a adapter who hold most EditText views. I want access them so i can get their text when inserted by the user

Comment: But you won't know which EditText is which from your list? And you won't be able to get the ones that have scrolled off the screen.  Why are you using a GridView, it sounds like you could use a ListView wrapped in a ScrollView. How many EditTexts are you expecting to use?

Comment: I expect to use a lot of views, in fact, it will be specified by the user. My purpose is to make a MatrixMultiplication acitivity.

Comment: the views are placed evenly on the screen, so i thought that with some math i could find them.But i don't understand very well how adapter works, it is the first time i'm using a custom. But for what you are saying, i feel like i don't have much control over it. I chose the grid just because the necessity of placing the views in rows/coluns format, i didn't think of anithyng else because i don't know them  very well yet

Comment: if you have a fixed number of views, it is likely better to use a fixed view. Try a `LinearLayout` with orientation horizontal and then more `LinearLayout`'s inside with orientation vertical.

Comment: o shit, i actually thought about it before trying the grid, but i didn't go with it because i thought it would be too much pain to nest the layouts dinamically USADHAUSDH

Comment: but i'm going to do it, i'm done being lazy. Thanks for your time Sir!